# Ways to travel from Mexico to South America over land

Tags: international-travel, transportation, sightseeing, overland, central-america

I'm looking to travel from Mexico down through Central America by land and am looking for the best way to do this and any issues people have had please!

Comment: Welcome! Please have a look a the [help] - open ended, broad and asking for recommendations is generally considered off topic - this is a Q&A site, not a forum. If you have specific problems - for example, how long does the border crossing between Mexico and Belize stay open each day?, but broad 'best way' questions will likely be put on hold.  Consider the [chat] for general ones like this though, people are happy to help!

Comment: no worries, please do feel free to edit, it sounds like an amazing trip and I'm sure you'll have tons of specific questions as you go.

Comment: It is in practice not possible to do this journey over land; you'll have to cross from Panama to Colombia by sea.

Answer (score 3):

I was in Panama in 2013 and was told it is not possible to cross the Colombian border by car/bus/train because there is no road in the middle of the jungle.
  In fact [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontera_entre_Colombia_y_Panam%C3%A1) says about the Panama-Colombia border:

> A hostile environment of tropical jungles. There is no road that goes
>   to the border because the Carretera Panamericana (the road that
>   crosses every central american country) is not finished. The only 2
>   borderline villages are Miel, in Panama, and Sapzurro, in Colombia, both
>   in the Caribbean coast.

I guess you'll have to travel by sea or air from Panama to Colombia.

Comment: The area is known in English as the [Darién gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dari%C3%A9n_Gap) for this reason.